# Set label with bold system font

Tags: ios, uilabel

I wish to programatically set the font of a label to system font Bold. I am using the following code to set the font but I do not know how to set it to Bold.

```
mylabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
```

Comment: use, mylabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to set the System font you Can go for

```
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
```

if you want to set the customs font you can use below

```
label.font = UIFont(name:"FontName-Bold", size: 16.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use system font

```
 label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
```

**OR**

Font attribute

```
label.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14.0)
```